# Rolling and slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

If a rigid disc purely rolls over a very rough surface before suddenly entering a slightly less rough surface would it slip?

Comment: What did you try to do? What is your line of reasoning?

Comment: I am doubtful about when transitioning between surfaces how friction behaves and whether it suddenly changes or gradually varies as it moves through rough to slightly less rough surface.

Comment: Also, I am unsure about the conditions under which rolling without slipping is maintained when transitioning between surfaces.

Comment: You should edit your question and add more informations, rather than giving them in the comments

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not static friction is being relied upon for pure rolling on the rougher surface. More information is needed to make that determination.

If it is, it may slip upon entering the smoother surface if the applied force that required static friction on the rougher surface to prevent slippage exceeds the maximum possible static friction force of the smoother surface.

If static friction was not required for pure rolling on the rougher surface, it will also not be required for pure rolling on the smoother surface.

Hope this helps.